# Getting an IE error after accepting a site's certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

There is a partner site, that I connect to through HTTPS and with a custom port. I am using Internet Explorer.

When I go to that URL, I get a prompt from Internet Explorer, saying "There is a problem with this website's security certificate".

I am given 2 options:

- Click here to close this webpage
- Continue to this website (not recommended)

I choose the 2nd option of course.

However, right after I do so, I get the following Internet Explorer error page:

"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage", saying there might be a problem with my internet connection, suggesting I diagnose connection problems, etc).

I tried adding that website to my "Trusted Sites" list, but still no use.

Can anyone troubleshoot this problem? I think it's a certificate related issue, because seeing the packets flow in and out of the firewall, it is all being permitted and I am not getting blocked at any stage.

Comment: I once had a problem like this, and it was not a certificate trouble at all; instead, the server was OpenSSL code which was sending zero-length records as part as some sort of vulnerability workaround, and the client was IE 6.0 which did not support zero-length records. The certificate thing was a total red herring.

Comment: So you are saying that basically Firefox should load it fine? Or alternatively just update to the latest version of IE?

Comment: He is just saying: try with some other browsers; and, also, the browser and OS versions are relevant information and should be included in your question.